# JAVA double to string with sign and without trailing zeros

Tags: java, string, double

I need to format a double value to string in such a way that it has a sign in front ("+" whether it's positive, "-" whether it's negative) and has no trailing zeros. For example:

```
Input: 1.5
Output: "+1.5"

Input: 1.0
Output: "+1"

Input: -123.123321
Output: "-123.123321"
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution is cleaner:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("+0.##############");
df.format(1.5);
```

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("+0.####;-#");